# Which of the following two pieces of code is faster or the same, and why?

Tags: performance, erlang

-record(test, {a = 10}).

test(Test) when is_record(Test,test) -> somethings.

or

test(#test{} = Test) -> somethings.

which is faster or the same? why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not too hard to test with the compiler.
To do that, I wrote this module…

```
-module my_mod.
-export [t1/1, t2/1].

-record(test, {a = 10}).

t1(Test) when is_record(Test,test) -> somethings.

t2(#test{} = _Test) -> somethings.
```

Then, I run `erlc -E my_mod.erl` and this is the resulting expanded code:

```
-file("my_mod.erl", 1).

-module(my_mod).

-export([t1/1,t2/1]).

-record(test,{a = 10}).

t1({test, _} = Test) when true ->
    somethings.

t2({test, _} = _Test) ->
    somethings.
```

So, basically… it's the same. Using `is_record(Test, test)` adds a useless guard (`true`) but that shouldn't make a difference in terms of *speed*.

Furthermore, if you use `erlc -S my_mod.erl`, to generate assembly listings, you get:

```
{module, my_mod}.  %% version = 0

{exports, [{module_info,0},{module_info,1},{t1,1},{t2,1}]}.

{attributes, []}.

{labels, 9}.


{function, t1, 1, 2}.
  {label,1}.
    {line,[{location,"my_mod.erl",6}]}.
    {func_info,{atom,my_mod},{atom,t1},1}.
  {label,2}.
    {test,is_tagged_tuple,{f,1},[{x,0},2,{atom,test}]}.
    {move,{atom,somethings},{x,0}}.
    return.


{function, t2, 1, 4}.
  {label,3}.
    {line,[{location,"my_mod.erl",8}]}.
    {func_info,{atom,my_mod},{atom,t2},1}.
  {label,4}.
    {test,is_tagged_tuple,{f,3},[{x,0},2,{atom,test}]}.
    {move,{atom,somethings},{x,0}}.
    return.


{function, module_info, 0, 6}.
  {label,5}.
    {line,[]}.
    {func_info,{atom,my_mod},{atom,module_info},0}.
  {label,6}.
    {move,{atom,my_mod},{x,0}}.
    {line,[]}.
    {call_ext_only,1,{extfunc,erlang,get_module_info,1}}.


{function, module_info, 1, 8}.
  {label,7}.
    {line,[]}.
    {func_info,{atom,my_mod},{atom,module_info},1}.
  {label,8}.
    {move,{x,0},{x,1}}.
    {move,{atom,my_mod},{x,0}}.
    {line,[]}.
    {call_ext_only,2,{extfunc,erlang,get_module_info,2}}.
```

As you can see, the two functions are, in fact, identical:

```
{function, …, 1, …}.
  {label,…}.
    {line,[{location,"my_mod.erl",…}]}.
    {func_info,{atom,my_mod},{atom,…},1}.
  {label,…}.
    {test,is_tagged_tuple,{f,…},[{x,0},2,{atom,test}]}.
    {move,{atom,somethings},{x,0}}.
    return.
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, which has solved my question

Answer (score -1):

maybe the second one.There's no concept of record during runtime, just tuple.

```
21> rd(test, {a = 10}).               
test
22> erlang:is_record({test, 1}, test).
true
```